# using asynchbeans instead of native jdk threads

Tags: multithreading, websphere

are there any performance limitations using IBM's asynchbeans? 
my apps jvm core dumps are showing numerous occurences of orphaned threads. Im currently using native jdk unmanaged threads. Is it worth changing over to managed threads?

Answer (score 1):

In my perspective asynchbeans are a workaround to create threads inside Websphere J2EE server. So far so good, websphere lets you create pool of "worker" threads, controlling this way the maximum number of threads, typical J2EE scalability concern.

I had some problems using asynchbeans inside websphere on "unmanaged" threads (hacked callbacks from JMS Listener via the "outlawed" setMessageListener). I was "asking for it" not using MDBs in the first place, but I have requisites that do not feet MDB way.